# Why am I seeing nothing for the command 'which appium' after installing through npm install -g appium@1.14.0?

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, python-venv

MacOS

I did the following steps:

1) mkvirtualenv --python=`which python3` opencv-ve 2)sudo pip3 install nodeenv 3) nodeenv -p 4) npm install -g appium@X.XX.X 5) which appium

Now the expected result for step 5 has to display path of appium.
But see no result. 
There is no appium installed even if I manually `cd` into folder -  /Users/sumanthvakacharla/.virtualenvs/opencv-ve **(Expected place)**

But In the installation logs, I see it is stored in /Users/sumanthvakacharla/.node/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/.bin/authorize-ios and is present when I manually `cd` there. But can't do anything with it.

**I also tried,**
`npm install -g npm`
`npm cache clean`
`npm update`
`npm install`
And re-installed appium. This has worked previously but not anymore.

May be am I setting the PATH variable wrong ? If yes, what can be the suggested path ?

Comment: To install via npm pleae try npm install -g appium and to verify the installed version type appium --version in the command line terminal . Optionally ,  you may want to run appium-doctor to ensure your system is set up properly:

$ npm install -g appium-doctor

Comment: To see the appium version, first of all the appium command has to work. It says no appium command found. Because it is not installed at proper place. Same will be applicable for appium-doctor. It has to be installed at the right place to leverage that command